# Electronic music inspired by Sci-Fi movies

Tags: electronic-music

As many other people I grew up watching science fiction movies and listening to electronic music, to the point that I developed a great passion about them. Recently I found out few songs which are inspired by sci-fi movies, I'm not talking about soundtracks, but about music composed by electronic artists who were, I guess, so moved by these movies that they decided to compose music inspired by them.

Right now I can remember few songs inspired by science fiction movies, and I wonder if there are more out there (I guess yes!).

---

### Blade Runner

[My Kingdom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdFKoZHzMQ0) by Future Sound Of London, it is inspired by Vangelis song [Rachel's Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIBKbhrniUQ) composed for the Blade Runner movie.

Another song with the same inspiration is [Rachel In Trance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKNEgrtUL6Y) by Zymotix.

Other two songs: [Blade Runner](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTgMJFuf7ls) by Remake, and the remix by [Maceo Plex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkhHLczEhC4).

### Blade Runner 2049

[Miracle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwRTbTAKa9s) by Rolo Green, it is inspired by Blade Runner too, more precisely by its sequel titled Blade Runner 2049. In fact in various parts of the song we can hear the quote "have you ever seen a miracle?" (said by the character Sapper Morton). In the mid part the is also a longer quote, which however I cannot identify.

### Interstellar

[Stay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4LxYhj_N2Q) by Kryder, inspired by Hans Zimmer soundtrack composed for the Interestellar movie.

---

These songs belong to different subgenres of electronic music: intelligent dance music (IDM), trance, deep tech, house. But I don't really care about labelling music since I appreciate electronic music in its various tastes.

I'm fascinated about the link between these two worlds, music and cinematography, and I'm very curious to listen to new music inspired by sci-fi movies, do you know some others?

Comment: I think [Perdition City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUQpHPPbdCI) by Ulver was not inspired by a sci-fi film, but it has a futuristic theme around it and it was composed as a soundtrack for a non-existent film.

Comment: Headscan used some samples from Blade Runner for songs on their "Pattern Recognition" album. "Slipstream Monocraft" uses a sample of the vocal track from "Tales of the Future". "Antenna Manifold" uses some audio from the Voight-Kampff test at the beginning of the movie.

Answer (score 1):

One genre with a rich potential for this kind of stuff is space ambient, psy ambient, or just ambient. Popular artists include: Solar Fields, Dreamstate Logic, Stelladrone, Carbon Based Lifeforms, etc.

Here is one example clearly based on Hitchhiker's guide to galaxy: [Stelardrone - Milliways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4FGQqoQK_w).
Go over their song lists and you are likely to find hundreds inspired by games, books, and movies.